# Rules for formatting the border of cells in a grouped tablix report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Does anyone know if there are rules dictating the order of the rendering of formatting of the borders of cells in a grouped tablix report?

I have a group - the formatting of the cells is behaving unpredictably and I'm guessing that there is an order that RS applies to it's formatting i.e if I've highlighted the whole group row and applied formatting X it will be applied either before or after the formatting I've applied on a single cell of that row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its parent -> child.

If you want an fixed width of 5in for example, you set it on the parent and its children will arrange themselves on those 5in.